# Auto Installing PWA in Vaadin

Tags: java, maven, progressive-web-apps, vaadin14

I'm slightly new to java and vaadin platform. Right now I need to auto install the PWA in vaadin framework. By auto install I mean when user gets in the website the PWA need to install without asking the user if they want to install. But I couldn't find a way to do that. I search nearly most of the vaadin tutorials and related subjects on internet. I know that most of the situations the auto installation is not recommended.

[image: PWA install button]

I don't want that install button to show up instead of that I want it to auto install the PWA.

Can you help me with that. Even showing me the way to do it will suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by default not possible as it would be too big security risk. There is some features in Chrome however that allows to manage it in corporate environment and push web apps to users in controlled manner.

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9367354?hl=en#zippy=